# Collapse dataframe by name, where integer columns are summed and factor columns are pasted

Tags: r

I am attempting to collapse a data frame by unique names that contain both supplemental integer and factor columns. The integers column needs to be summed for unique 'Name' values and the factor column needs to have all values pasted alongside one another like this:

```
Name        Number         Location
RUDU          6               SiteA
RUDU          4               SiteB
YHBL          50              SiteA
YHBL          60              SiteB
```

Collapsed by name to:

```
Name        Number         Location
RUDU          10              SiteA,SiteB
YHBL          110             SiteA,SiteB
```

I have played around a bit with ddplyr which works for the integer portion however I am at a loss at how to aggregate the factor portion of my request.

Comment: I'm not sure how the code would be, but to spark an idea, try splitting up into two processes. Add the numbers together and save as variable then run `newDf <- data.frame(unique(oldDf))` and replace the numbers with the new variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a possible `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(Mumber = sum(Number), Location = toString(Location)), by = Name]
#    Name Mumber     Location
# 1: RUDU     10 SiteA, SiteB
# 2: YHBL    110 SiteA, SiteB
```

And as you mentioned `plyr`, here's a `dplyr` possible solution

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(
            Mumber = sum(Number), 
            Location = toString(Location)
            )

# Source: local data table [2 x 3]
# 
#   Name Mumber     Location
# 1 RUDU     10 SiteA, SiteB
# 2 YHBL    110 SiteA, SiteB
```

Comment: plus one for `toString`

Comment: `setDT(df)[, list(Mumber = sum(Number), Location = .(Location)), by = Name]`. solution without `toString`

Comment: @plafort it will convert `Location` to a list though.

Comment: I see. Keeping it as a vector would work better in most situations.

Answer (score 2):

**dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
    group_by_(~Name) %>% 
    summarize_(Number=~sum(Number), Location=~paste(Location, collapse=','))
```

**base R**

```
merge(aggregate(Number ~ Name, data=d, FUN=sum), aggregate(Location ~ Name, data=d, FUN=paste, collapse=','))
```

Answer (score 2):

Two more methods for reference.

**Function: tapply()**

```
data.frame(
  Number = with(df1, tapply(Number, Name, sum)),
  Location = with(df1, tapply(Location, Name, toString))                  
)

#      Number     Location
# RUDU     10 SiteA, SiteB
# YHBL    110 SiteA, SiteB
```

**Function: by()**

```
data.frame(cbind(
  Number = with(df1, by(Number, Name, sum)),
  Location =  with(df1, by(Location, Name, toString))
  )
)

#      Number     Location
# RUDU     10 SiteA, SiteB
# YHBL    110 SiteA, SiteB
```

**Data**

```
# df1 <- read.table(text='Name        Number         Location
# RUDU          6               SiteA
# RUDU          4               SiteB
# YHBL          50              SiteA
# YHBL          60              SiteB', header=T)
```